# How to replace only particular dots in the string?

Tags: python, string, replace

How to replace only particular dots in the text string?:

```
string_expample = '123|4.3|123.54|sdflk|hfghjkkf.ffg..t.s..9.7..tg..3..654..2.fd'
```

I need to get only dots that are 1 and between 2 digits( 4.3 from |4.3|; 3.5 from 123.54, etc.) 
be replaced by commas in the original string, is it possible?
If so, how?
So, the result string must be:

```
string_final = '123|4,3|123,54|sdflk|hfghjkkf.ffg..t.s..9,7..tg..3...654..2.fd'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re

string_example = '123|4.3|123.54|sdflk|hfghjkkf.ffg..t.s..4..tg..3...654..2.fd'

string_final = re.sub(r'(\d)\.(\d)', r'\1,\2', string_example)
print(string_final)
```

```
123|4,3|123,54|sdflk|hfghjkkf.ffg..t.s..4..tg..3...654..2.fd
```

We use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to find "`digit` `.` `digit`" (the digits are captured into groups with parentheses) and replace them with "`group 1` `,` `group 2`" (the groups are the corresponding digits).